# What is the reason why my DOMXPath chokes without warnings or errors

Tags: php, domxpath

Here is my code below.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument(); 
$dom->loadHTML($source); // Html String
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$meta_keywords = $xpath->query("//meta[translate(@name,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'keywords']");


try
{

    if($meta_keywords != null)
    {
         $keyword = $meta_keywords->item(0)->getAttribute("content");

    }
}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. And when it doesn't work it causes my script to exit without errors warnings and without exceptions.

Comment: PHPDOM is **VERY** sensitive to malformed html. it'll puke at the barest hint of something even being POSSIBLY malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PHPDOM is VERY sensitive to malformed html. it'll puke at the barest
>   hint of something even being POSSIBLY malformed. – Marc B Nov 3 '11 at
>   17:44

I decided to use TIDY for my HTML strings.